# Open PDF attachment from an Outlook email

Tags: windows-10-mobile, outlook, pdf

I have Windows Phone 10, Outlook, and all latest updates. I installed Microsoft's PDF reader app (I also tried the Adobe app).

I open an email and tap on a PDF attachment. Instead of opening, it tells me that I need an app and should search the store. I click "Yes", it takes me to the store, and a blank page is shown.

*How do I open PDFs in Outlook?*

PS: I also tried saving the file to the phone, and opening it in the File Explorer app. But it doesn't get saved, and the file is not there!

Comment: Is this happening with all attached pdfs or just one. I doubt if might be the pdf is corrupted.

Comment: By default, edge opens the pdf documents and i just tried it now, please try with other attachments, as Swetha said, it might be a corrupted pdf!

Comment: All PDFs. Actually this problem has been reported before many times. Pity they haven't fixed it yet. Images open properly, just PDFs that don't.

Comment: @qphone Uninstall the Microsoft's PDF reader app. Then install an another reader like Foxit or Adobe. It worked for me that way. I think it is problem with the PDF reader app.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same behaviour. But the JPG attachments are also unable to open. If I click to forward the email, I can open the attachments without any problem. 
It's simply a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I re-installed the [PDF reader app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/PDF-Reader/9WZDNCRFJ3NL) from Microsoft and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

PDF reader app is about EOL. Open PDF using Edge now on-wards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all download the PDF Attachment from Outlook. Then click on it. A list of PDF readers option will be shown to you(I have Adobe Acrobat Reader and PDF Reader), click any one. The PDF will open.